# Microsoft Edge displays the background above the other elements

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to solve a problem on this website. (http://www.yunke.es)

In IE (10, 11) and (Chome, Firefox, etc) works fine but in Edge the backgrounds of the different sections hidden all over the web and it's not possible access to the contents (text and images) I have done tests changing Css properties... for example "position", but is not working well. Any idea?

```css
#backgrounds {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .6s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .6s ease-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-out;
    background: url(../img/loader.gif) no-repeat center center #000;
}

#contents, #layer-1, #layer-2 {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .6s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .6s ease-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="backgrounds" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
 <article class="item-0" style="height: 773px;"></article>
 <article class="item-1" style="height: 773px; background-position: 0px 0px;"></article>
 <article class="item-2" style="height: 1161px;"></article>
 <article class="item-3" style="height: 773px;"></article>
 <article class="item-4" style="height: 773px;"></article>
 <article class="item-5" style="height: 773px;"></article>
 <article class="item-6" style="height: 2146px;"></article>
 <article class="item-7" style="height: 773px;"></article>
 <article class="item-8" style="height: 773px;"></article>
 <article class="item-9" style="height: 773px;"></article>
 <article class="item-10" style="height: 1040px;">
  <div class="crazy">
   <img src="http://yunke.es/assets/img/background-6-1.png" style="right: -442.013%;">
  </div>
 </article>
</div>

<div id="contents" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); visibility: visible;">
 
 <article class="item-0" style="height: 927.6px;"></article>
 
 <article class="item-1" style="height: 927.6px;">
  <div class="mask" style="height: 773px; transform: translate3d(0px, -309.2px, 0px);">
   <img class="masked" src="http://yunke.es/assets/img/background-2-1.png" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 309.2px, 0px);">
  </div>
  <div class="mask" style="height: 773px; transform: translate3d(0px, -309.2px, 0px);">
   <img class="masked eyes-open" src="http://yunke.es/assets/img/background-2-2.png" style="visibility: hidden; transform: translate3d(0px, 309.2px, 0px);">
  </div>
 </article>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please share HTML/CSS if you want people to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge seems to have a Bug with the property translate3d using pixel units. Transforming the "px" in "%" will solve the Problem.

Comment: How did you conclude this? If you have a reduction, please consider posting it on http://bugs.microsoftedge.com.

Comment: I got the same issue in a project and fix it using "%" instead of px. I don't really care about the Bugs for Edge because I'd never seen an appropriate Browser done by microsoft ;-). The Edge developers have to test their Browser themselfs

Comment: I'm an engineer on the Edge team; we test thoroughly. But I also watch Stack Overflow for any scenarios we don't have covered, so that we can improve with time.